# Flutter: How to have Container/Column with fix height

Tags: flutter, user-interface, containers

The layout have uses column with Text and Image.  The data change based from a list and some text/image are nil.  How to make the container takes the same height when only one data is present?

Thanks.

```
      body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'This is Container/Column1.  It have two widgets, Text and Image.  How to make the height of the container same even if one the the widget is removed/null?',
            ),
            Image.asset('assets/index.jpg')
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('This is Container/Column2.  This will have additional widgets.'),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Text('Next Button',
```

),),),],),),],),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first approach: add a fixed height to your container

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        // this will give the container a fixed height of 0.4 from the screen height
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'This is Container/Column1.  It have two widgets, Text and Image.  How to make the height of the container same even if one the the widget is removed/null?',
            ),
            Image.asset('assets/index.jpg')
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('This is Container/Column2.  This will have additional widgets.'),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Next Button',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

second approach: if one of them is null add a `SizedBox()` with your prefered height

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            someCondition ? Text(
              'This is Container/Column1.  It have two widgets, Text and Image.  How to make the height of the container same even if one the the widget is removed/null?',
            ) : SizedBox(height : 40)
            someCondition ? Image.asset('assets/index.jpg') : SizedBox(height : 40)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('This is Container/Column2.  This will have additional widgets.'),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Next Button',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: if this is what you're looking for kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap column with Expanded. Second is to have fixed height for contained. If you have this problem with ListView inside another widget and have problems, use shrinkWrap as true inside a ListView. And again for your problem (which person above failed to understand) is that you need or fixed value for height or use Expanded (as much space as possible) or Flexible (least space possible).